# using name value pair to update record in database - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Have been looking this up in Google but could not find anything.

Wanted to know if there is a way in SQL Server 2005 that I could use Name Value pairs to update records in the db.

I have a list of Name Value pairs and want to update all the records where Name could be found as a columm value (something that you would specify in where clause) and if the record is found ... update the record with the Value paired with the name

For instance, something like

```
update X set column_value = <Value paired with the Name> where column_name = <Name from the list>
```

P.S. I have a list of more than 1000 records and this could be more.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way is to store your pair values in separate table. E.g. :

```
map(name,value)
```

And update your table using join. E.g :

```
update m1 set m1.column_value = m2.value
from mytable m1 join map m2 on m1.column_name = m2.name
```

Comment: loved your reply, but I cannot really create a table there :(

Comment: You must have a table where this name,value reside you can use that table

Comment: BTW if i understand correctly you are looking for a Dynamic SQL solution.

Comment: @simranNarula - In which format exactly your pair values are stored ?

Comment: its name value file separated by spaces and new line chars, each new line is a pair

Comment: And you read the file line by line ? If so, you can update your table per each line. It is not clear enough what exactly the problem you are trying to solve...